# MVC with Java EE 6/7 JPA, JTA, EJB3, CDI

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, frameworks

I like REST, JPA, JTA, EJB3, CDI & Co. And I like MVC web frameworks, but interesting ones like Play! are not Java EE.

So, just for fun, would it make sense at all to think about something like:

- A servlet that accepts REST style URLs and dispatches to managed controllers that can inject EJBs and so on through CDI
- The controllers forward/redirect to simple views that act as templates and can use responsive frameworks like Bootstrap

Or does Java EE imply JSF and really nothing else?

Answer (score 1):

I had a look into this topic, wrote a simple JSF webapp and found some interesting resources.

This answer to a related stackoverflow question nicely explains how MVC maps to JSF: [Understanding JSF as a MVC framework](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10114158/709426)

Regarding REST style URLs, [prettyfaces](http://ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/) looks promising.

JSF has nice [templating](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giqxp.html) similar to Apache Tiles, and pages can be very simple using plain HTML and CSS with EL.

So, maybe no need to think about/look for something else than JSF and just use it?

Comment: Another option is to consider JAX-RS + Thymeleaf for HTML5 templating.

True MVC will be available in Java EE 8 as part JSR 371 (https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=371).