# Which is best architecture MVC or MVVM or MVP for iOS

Tags: ios, model-view-controller, mvvm, architecture, mvp

There are 3 architecture I found which are used for app development. Which one is the best for iOS development? 
Thanks.

Comment: this should be potentially moved to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: see this
http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254571/4511978

Comment: There is no best architecture. Different situations call for different solutions. As it is, i think this question is too broad. If you describe what you are trying to achieve in detail, maybe we can help you choose one that suits your needs.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

**MVC** is best for iOS development.

Important advantages of MVC Model:

**1. Faster development process**

**2. Ability to provide multiple views**

**3. Support for asynchronous technique**

**4. Modification does not affect the entire model**

**5. MVC model returns the data without formatting**

**6. SEO friendly Development platform**

also check following links:

[What are the main advantages of MVC pattern over the old fashioned 3-layer pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573419/what-are-the-main-advantages-of-mvc-pattern-over-the-old-fashioned-3-layer-patte)

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/the-advantages-of-using-design-patterns-in-ios-development/

https://www.raywenderlich.com/132662/mvc-in-ios-a-modern-approach

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/05/better-architecture-for-ios-apps-model-view-controller-pattern/