# 3-tier website error handling design

Tags: error-handling, 3-tier

I am working on a 3-tier based website design using web-forms.  With the basic layout of Presentation->Logic->Data.

Every class in each tier contains `List<strings> Errors`. So if an error happens on the Data tier, it can be copied to the Logic tier, and then exposed to the Presentation tier. The idea is to let the end user know an error happened and basic information on its location; logging will be used hand-in-hand for greater details of the errors for trouble shooting.

I have read of this parent-child style of error passing, just wondering if anyone has used this approach?

Comment: Presentation->Logic->Data sounds like a new way of saying MVC. I wouldn't describe this as a parent-child relationship.

Comment: I think it is actually older.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture

Comment: The parent-child relationship is referring to the errors not the program design.

Comment: Noted by: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10739914/what-is-the-difference-between-3-tier-architecture-and-a-mvc