# Difference between 3Tier Architecture and (MVC or MVP)

Tags: asp.net, design-patterns, web-applications, web-architecture

I just want to know the difference between 3Tier Architecture and (MVC or MVP).

I am asking this question because i am C++ developer and new web development. I read various internet resources and i found both the same, the base line is that we have following 3 layers:

- 3 Tier Architecture: Presentation
  Layer, Business Logic Layer and Data
  Access Layer
- MVC: View, Controller and Model
- MVP: View, Presenter and Model

I found a good [resource](http://assets.devx.com/articlefigs/18289.jpg) about difference between MVP and MVC, but still confuse with 3 Tier Architecture.

Note: By 3 Tier i am referring to 3 logical layer not physical layers.

Comment: Please see your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592182/can-i-say-that-mvp-3-tier-archi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this question [MVC Vs n-tier architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698220/mvc-vs-n-tier-architecture).  It doesn't address MVP specifically, but given that MVP and MVC appear to be two different takes on the same problem, it should help you out.