# A reference to 'Class' could not be added, circular dependency

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I  build a project in C# with Visual studio 2010.
I work with MVC model, (model-view-control)
and I created 3 diffrent projects (one for each layer) .
Now I try to reference each layer to other. 
so I added:
1. reference of the view in the control.
2. reference of the model in the control.

but now I need to add reference of the Control in the View, and I get an error about circular dependency.

[image: error]
how can I solve it?

Comment: To clarify, what are the 3 projects you created? The error you're getting is because 2 projects are referencing each other. This isn't allowed.

Comment: MVC != 3-tier architecture http://stackoverflow.com/questions/698220/mvc-vs-n-tier-architecture

Comment: Hi,
I have 3 projects.
view, model and control.
and I have to add reference of the control in the view, and another one in the view of the control. Why it's not allowed?

Comment: It might work better to have the Controllers in the same project with the Views. But the Controller action methods are very short, and they call more complex methods in a Business Logic Layer in another project.

Comment: Thanks DOK. thats whay I made in the begin.. but I have requirement
for 3 diffrent projects .

Comment: Quite often, the Models are in a separate project that is referenced by the UI, BLL and the DAL. That would give you four projects.

Comment: but what you described it's architecture of MVVM no?
I need to do only 3 projects in the regular MVC architecture .

Comment: I believe in pure MVC (which is probaly the goal of the exercise with such strange requirement) there should be no circular dependency: View depends on Model (and possibly on Controller), Controller depends on Model, Model does not depend on either...  One will likely still need 4th project for overall app at least for managing commands from view to controller.